How to skip default named arguments while setting a named variadic argument in a function call?
I have an existing method:
public function dbQuery(
    string $query,
    bool $flag1 = false,
    int $flag2 = SOME_DEFAULT,
    bool $flag3 = false
)

Now I want to adapt it so it is possible to pass in binding values as variadic arguments, but without breaking the current interface (I know arg flags are an anti-pattern), to be:
public function dbQuery(
    string $query,
    bool $flag1 = false,
    int $flag2 = SOME_DEFAULT,
    bool $flag3 = false,
    mixed ...$params
)

How can I then call dbQuery while keeping the default flags while passing in params?
I've tried:

->dbQuery('my query', params: [1, 2, 3]); but it comes through as an array in the first variadic arg e.g. $params = [[1, 2, 3]]
->dbQuery('my query', params: ...[1, 2, 3]); is invalid syntax
->dbQuery('my query', ...['params' => [1, 2, 3]]); same result as option 1

Nothing with quite this usage is shown in:
https://wiki.php.net/rfc/variadics
or https://wiki.php.net/rfc/named_params
Although in the later RFC it explictly shows that default named arguments before variadics is a valid signature, but not how to access the variadics.

Some suggest dbQuery(...['query'=> 'my query', 'params' => $params]); but I would rather ask why did you make it mixed ...$params instead of array $params in the first place, if you intend to provide it in bulk, not as separate variables

Sadly the spread all is still passing params in the first vardic param.
passing params as an array would work but I would like to upgrade the mixed type to something stricter e.g. int|float|string|null
which cannot be done with an array

I fell in love with named parameters at first sight, but I don't see a way to achieve what you seek with the available syntax.
I mean, even if you passed an array of parameters through to a guard function which spread the array and used type hinting, you could trigger fatal errors on non-scalar values, but a boolean value would be coalesced to an integer.
const SOME_DEFAULT = 1;

function validateParams(int|float|string|null ...$params) {
    var_dump($params);
}

function dbQuery(
    string $query,
    bool $flag1 = false,
    int $flag2 = SOME_DEFAULT,
    bool $flag3 = false,
    array $params = []
) {
    validateParams(...$params);
    var_dump(
        $query,
        $flag1,
        $flag2,
        $flag3,
        $params
    );
}

dbQuery(
    'foo', params: ['fizz', 'buzz', false]
);

Maybe you can be convinced to accept an array of parameters, then run a validation process on all elements and throw an exception for non-qualifying payloads.
Or maybe spread the params array into the next method call and allow it to complain about inappropriate data types.

Thank you for your answer! A no is still an answer. Shame these two new language features don't play nicer together, good suggestion with the validation method, I've tested it the bool int isn't an issue for code with the declare(strict_types = 1); however declare strict doesn't seem to work in the REPL
